# How to "Undo" after macro run?

Tags: vba, ms-project

I am running a code, that changes the format of the task's row, based on a value in `Text1` field.

If I change the `Duration`, or `Finish` or some other values when I update the schedule, the value of `Text1` (customized field) is modified as well. As a result of that value, I am formatting the background color and the font color.

Once I run this code, I can't use the regular "Undo" so I can't get the values to return to their previous state.

How do I create the "***Custom Undo***"?

***ThisProject* Code**

```vb
Private Sub Project_Change(ByVal pj As Project)
    ' enable class to modify the Task format on Project change (when a task is changed)
    
    StatusRYGFieldUpdate
    
End Sub
```

***Regular Code Module***

```vb
Option Explicit
    
Public StatusRYGView                As New clsTskUpdate
Public UpdateViewFlag               As Boolean
Public TskIDChanged                 As Long
    
    
Sub StatusRYGFieldUpdate()
    
    ' this Sub is triggered once a task is modified
    ' if the Field being modifed is related to "Text1"
        
    Dim CurTskID    As Long
    
    Set StatusRYGView.ProjApp = Application
    
    Application.Calculation = pjManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    If UpdateViewFlag Then
        CurTskID = TskIDChanged ' save Row ID
        FormatTask (TskIDChanged) ' call the Sub that formats the cell (send the taskId)
    End If
    
    Application.Calculation = pjAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
End Sub
    
'===========================================================
    
Sub FormatTask(TskID)
    
    Dim Tsk         As Task
    
    If UpdateViewFlag Then
        
        SelectTaskField TskID, "Text1", False
        Set Tsk = ActiveCell.Task ' set the Task to current cell's Task
        SelectRow Row:=TskID, RowRelative:=False
        
        ' format entire row first
        Select Case Tsk.Text1 ' Get the Field's used field, not name
            Case "R"
                FontEx CellColor:=7, Color:=0
                FontEx Italic:=False
                
            Case "Complete"
                FontEx Italic:=True 
                FontEx CellColor:=15, Color:=14 ' Background Silver ; font Gray
                
        End Select
                
        ' format "Status" field
        SelectTaskField TskID, "Text1", False
             
        Select Case Tsk.Text1 ' Get the Field's used field, not name
            Case "R"
              ' Font Color:=pjWhite ' Font White
                FontEx Italic:=False
                FontEx CellColor:=1, Color:=7 ' Background Red ; font White
                                                          
            Case "Complete"
                FontEx Italic:=True '  Font Italic
                FontEx CellColor:=15, Color:=14 ' Background Silver ; font Gray
                            
        End Select
    End If ' UpdateViewFlag is True
    
End Sub
```

***clsTskUpdate* Class Module**

```vb
Option Explicit
    
Public WithEvents ProjApp   As Application
    
Private Sub ProjApp_ProjectBeforeTaskChange(ByVal Tsk As Task, ByVal Field As PjField, ByVal NewVal As Variant, Cancel As Boolean)
    
    ' Sub (in "clsTskUpdate" Class) is triggered once a task is modified
    ' if the Field being modifed is related to "Text1"
    ' then the UpdateViewFlag is being raised, and the Tsk.ID (task's row) is saved to TskIDChanged variable
          
    UpdateViewFlag = False
    TskIDChanged = 0
    
    Select Case Field
        Case pjTaskActualFinish
            If Not NewVal Like Format(Tsk.ActualFinish, myDateFormat) Then ' need to modify date format to "dd/mm/yy"
                LastValue = Tsk.ActualFinish
                UpdateViewFlag = True
                TskIDChanged = Tsk.ID
            End If
                                        
        Case pjTaskStart
            If Not NewVal Like Format(Tsk.Start, myDateFormat) Then ' need to modify date format to "dd/mm/yy"
                LastValue = Tsk.Start
                UpdateViewFlag = True
                TskIDChanged = Tsk.ID
            End If
        
        Case pjTaskDuration
            If Not NewVal Like (Tsk.Duration / 480) & "*" Then ' need to divide by 480 (in minutes) and add `*` wild-card for "days"
                LastValue = Tsk.Duration / 480
                UpdateViewFlag = True
                TskIDChanged = Tsk.ID
            End If
            
        Case pjTaskPercentComplete
            If Not NewVal Like Tsk.PercentComplete Then
                LastValue = Tsk.PercentComplete
                UpdateViewFlag = True
                TskIDChanged = Tsk.ID
            End If
            
        ' other possible Case Scenarios in the future
    
    End Select
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Please clarify which version of MS Project you are using by updating the question title.

Comment: @RachelHettinger  it's 2007,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Project 2007 added a pair of methods, [OpenUndoTransaction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866344.aspx) and [CloseUndoTransaction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864164.aspx), that create a single undo entry for the user to undo an entire macro.

Add these methods to procedure StatusRYGFieldUpdate like this:

```
Sub StatusRYGFieldUpdate()

    Dim CurTskID    As Long

    Set StatusRYGView.ProjApp = Application

    Application.OpenUndoTransaction "Status RYG Field Update"
    Application.Calculation = pjManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If UpdateViewFlag Then
        CurTskID = TskIDChanged ' save Row ID
        FormatTask (TskIDChanged) ' call the Sub that formats the cell (send the taskId)
    End If

    Application.Calculation = pjAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.CloseUndoTransaction

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Rachel ! This is a powerful capability I wasn't able to find in Google for the past few years. I guess I didn't know exactly the search term. and where to search. One thing though, when using this it actually doesn't return to the previous step. When I select 1 step before (in the undo list), which is `"Set TaskField"`, then it works (this is 1 undo list  before the last `"Status RYG Field Update"`. Do you know why ?

Comment: @ShaiRado The paired Undo methods should wrap around all of the code; I edited the answer to put the `OpenUndoTransaction` method as the very first method called and put `CloseUndoTransaction` as the very last method. Also note that the last call to the `ScreenUpdating` method should be set back to `True`.

Comment: This is great, thanks so much ! You're my go to-guy (girl) on MS-Project VBA (wait for my next one)